# How to properly terminate/clear/stop/cancel a thread that was started from another thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

One of my threads is creating another thread to do something in a particular interval. It does so by timers.

Now when the original thread is stopped, the other thread is still running and I can not make it stop.

How can I properly terminate the 'thread'?:

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                sleep(1000);
                // do something
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"new invoked caught the exception!");
            return;
        }
    }
};

public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG,"ConnectedThread.run: Reading from InStream socket");
            while (true) {
                thread.start();
                Log.e(TAG,"starting additional thread");
                // Read from the InputStream
                int inB;
                inB = mmInStream.read();
                if (inB != -1) mAccessoryInfo.addCharacter((byte) inB);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "TADA InStream read exception, disconnected "
                    + e.getMessage());
            // stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Pinger.class));
            thread = null;
            connectionLost();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In general, you don't want to have a while(true) loop in your thread. Create a flag variable, (eg. "running") and use while(running) instead. This allows the thread to end itself when running=false, and you can use Thread.join() to block until it does.

Comment: If the second thread that you are starting can be run in a loop by nature, you can consider using a boolean value to break out of the loop and allow it to terminate gracefully rather than interrupting it or trying to stop it. like how  thomas88wp above has suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Hi thread is stop by kill() or stop() or destroy method of thread but this all are              
deprecated so dont kill the thread thread is automatically destroy after done its work.   
 so   
if you want to do any work use handler like this not thread in therad.
new Thread() {

        public void run() {

            try {
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.arg2 = 0;
                handle.sendMessage(msg);
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            }

            //

        }

    }.start();
 and make handler in ur activity like this
 public static Handler handle = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        if (msg.arg2 == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "No data to sync.",    
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else if (msg.arg2 == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Data Sync Completed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Data Sync not Completed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to interrupt the thread. The "normal" thing is to change the `while(true)` to `while(!isInterrupted)`, but as you are catching that exception above the while-loop it will go to the catch-block when you interrupt it. You can interrupt the thread by calling `thread.interrupt()`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are willing to do, maybe one or more handler/looper threads are what you want.

The code example is given in the Looper docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html ,
and the Handler class 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html 
provides methods (like postAtTime()) that you might use.

Answer (score 0):

Im a little confused when you say  you have a "thread" starting another "thread" do you mean an `Activity` is starting a thread and it is the `Activity` being destroyed and leaving an orphaned thread running? If that is the case then I would request to close the thread in the `Activity's` `onDestroy()` method.

within `onDestroy()`:

```
  ...
  if(yourThread != null){
    yourThread.interrupt();
  }
  ...
```

but i'd be a little concerned with using timers like that, is there no other way to achieve your goal? ie, Async Tasks and using Flags of when tasks Start / Complete

Comment: You're going to have to interrupt `yourThread`before you set it to null or it'll throw a `NullPointerException`. Also, no real need to set it to null.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) statements in java util concurrent framework.

The parent threads code will be like

```
public class Worker implements Callable<Boolean>
{
    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception 
    { 
        //Your worker code here
    }
}

void callingmethod()
{
    //Three threads executing upon five worker modules.

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3); 

    List<Worker> list = new ArrayList<Worker>(5);  //For example 5 workers.

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        list.add(new Worker());
    }

    List<Future<Boolean>> futures = executor.invokeAll(list);

    for(Future<Boolean> future : futures)
    {
    future.get();
    }

    executor.shutdown();

    executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

the statement future.get means that, the thread that runs the calling method will block until all workers have returned after performing the work.